# Manually Installed App's Priority

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any priority-wise difference between apps installed manually with APK file and apps downloaded from Google Play Store?

Comment: What is an app's priority?

Comment: Process priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no effect on process priority based on where the app came from. Process priority is determined by the state of that process (e.g., foreground).